# QTextCursor insert text with format problem after paragraphSeparator

Tags: qt, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

Hy Guys, I have this code

```cpp
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextDocument>

struct PartProperty
{
    enum e
    {
        Size = QTextFormat::UserProperty,
        Number,
        TagInfo,
    };
};

struct TagInfo
{
    inline TagInfo() : tagType( Unpaired ), tagCharType( TagMiddle )
    {
    }

    enum TagType
    {
        Unpaired,
        PairedOpen,
        PairedClose
    };

    enum TagCharType
    {
        TagBegin,
        TagMiddle,
        TagEnd
    };

    TagType tagType;
    TagCharType tagCharType;
};

void scanDocument( QTextDocument * document )
{
    if (!document)
        return;
    QTextCursor cursor( document );
    QTextCharFormat format = cursor.charFormat();
    auto text = document->toRawText();
    while( !cursor.atEnd() )
    {
        qDebug() << document->characterAt(cursor.position()) << ", " << text.at(cursor.position()) << ": " << (format.hasProperty( PartProperty::TagInfo ) ? QString("%1").arg(format.property( PartProperty::TagInfo ).value<TagInfo>().tagCharType) : "no tagInfo" );
        cursor.movePosition( QTextCursor::NextCharacter );
        format = cursor.charFormat();
    }
}

void writeExtendedTag( QTextCursor & cursor, TagInfo::TagType tagType)
{
    QTextCharFormat charFormat = cursor.document()->begin().charFormat();

    QTextCharFormat beginCharFormat = charFormat;
    TagInfo beginTagInfo;
    beginTagInfo.tagType = tagType;
    beginTagInfo.tagCharType = TagInfo::TagBegin;
    beginCharFormat.setProperty( PartProperty::TagInfo, QVariant::fromValue( beginTagInfo ) );

    cursor.insertText( QString( QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter ), beginCharFormat );

    scanDocument(cursor.document());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextDocument doc1;

    QTextCursor cursor1(&doc1);
    cursor1.insertText( " ");

    qDebug() << "first doc";

    writeExtendedTag( cursor1, TagInfo::Unpaired );


    QTextDocument doc2;

    QTextCursor cursor2(&doc2);
    cursor2.insertText( QString(QChar::ParagraphSeparator) );

    qDebug() << "second doc";

    writeExtendedTag( cursor2, TagInfo::Unpaired );

}
```

that outputs

```
first doc
' ' ,  ' ' :  "no tagInfo"
'\ufffc' ,  '\ufffc' :  "no tagInfo"
second doc
'\u2029' ,  '\u2029' :  "no tagInfo"
'\ufffc' ,  '\ufffc' :  "0"
```

What is the problem? Why does the paragraph separator works differently? I tried to debug but got inside QTextDocumentPrivate where things are pretty pretty complex at first sight.

Can you help me either understand what does `QTextDocumentPrivate` does with format in functions like `split`, either help how to insert properly formated object replacement char?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem is in QTextCursor.

While inserting one of the following characters:

```cpp
#define QTextBeginningOfFrame QChar(u'\xfdd0')
#define QTextEndOfFrame QChar(u'\xfdd1')

const QSet<QChar> textDocumentNewBlockCharsSet = {u'\n', QChar::ParagraphSeparator, QTextBeginningOfFrame, QTextEndOfFrame, u'\r'};
```

QTextCursor inserts block and denotes it with an **aditional SegmentSeparator** And doubles the inserted format on both chars.